# How can recognize machine names from another domain in the same network?

Tags: domain-name-system, windows-server-2012-r2

i have in my network 2 domains, the both in Windows server 2012 R2

Domain A: Main domain

Domain B: demo domain to make some test.

I need my DNS recognize the name of the machines in domain B, for example mail-server.domainB.com from any machine in domain A. So i don't know how to configure the DNS in domain A to resolve my problem.

PD: Can avoid the domain federation to do this?

Any suggestion? Thanks!

Best Regards, Buscatrufas.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to do this.  The easiest if you are willing to work with FQDNs instead of just short NetBIOS names is to set conditional forwarders for the remote domain on each side.  See here: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc794735(v=ws.10).aspx

You could use this in conjunction with both domain's DNS suffixes on every computer if you are ok with keeping unique names for every computer cross-domain.  This would allow you to query/ping something like "ping BOB" and it would first try BOB.domainA and then try BOB.domainB which would forward to the other domain (again using conditional forwarders).

When you say "domain federation" I can't tell if you are talking cross-forest or if you meant a domain trust within a forest.  If you want to setup a trust and let the DNS servers replicate zone information between them you can follow this guide: https://blog.ed.gs/2014/02/24/two-way-active-directory-cross-domain-trust/

If you are talking DNS resolution across forests, then conditional forwarders like at the beginning here will work well enough if you don't want to federate/trust across the forests.  Again, bear in mind you will want to use FQDNs when pinging or trying to access something on the other forest/domain unless you are willing to add DNS suffixes for each computer or server.